# How to generate Monthly and Weekly report in Mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to display the data on a monthly and weekly basis, I already searched lot of stuff about this but what i found doesn't answer my question. Here is what my table looks like:

```
---------------
+ tblcomplain +
---------------
+ id          +
+ status      +
+ complain    +
+ dateposted  +
---------------
```

Comment: can u add some sample data as well, also the create statement of your table

Comment: do u tried anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your column is `dateposted` is of type timestamp/datetime:

For Weekly Report:

```
select count(*) as totalWeeklycomplaints from tblcomplain group by week(dateposted);
```

For Monthly Report:

```
select count(*) as totalMothlycomplaints from tblcomplain group by month(dateposted);
```

Comment: Hi, does this method takes in consideration for different years data?

Comment: Hi, you can modify the query as following : 

select count(*) as totalMothlycomplaints, month(dateposted) as postedmonth, year(dateposted) as postyear from tblcomplain group by postedmonth, postyear;

This should give you the count of complaints in each month of every year available in database.

Answer (score 0):

For weekly basis

```
SELECT 
    *, EXTRACT(WEEK FROM add_date) AS w1
FROM
    product_alert_stock
ORDER BY w1 , add_date ASC
```

For Monthly basis

```
SELECT 
    *, EXTRACT(Month FROM add_date) AS m1
FROM
    product_alert_stock
ORDER BY m1 , add_date ASC
```